# Using the same storage drive with dual partitions

Tags: windows, macos, partitioning, multi-boot

I'd like to use a dual partition from my ssd (Windows 7 & OS X).

I would also like them both to share my two internal SATA hard drives (which is generally where all my additional files that are kept aside from the apps on the ssd that I use all the time).

There has to be a solution for this, but I don't know what it's called to even search for documentation about it.

Just looking for a step in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Mac, use [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/).

You can just partition your other internal drives as you see fit, but if you want both systems to be able to read and write, the options are a bit limited. I think the more recent Boot Camp drivers include full HFS+ support, but I'm not sure (and you can forget files such as OS X disk images -- .dmg, .sparseimage, .sparsebundle) -- on Windows. The "safe" way is to partition as FAT32 from the Mac OS X system, as it can be used by both.

Comment: Be careful though: Vista and Windows 7 don't like FAT32.

Comment: @Randolph: Even for non-system disks?

Comment: Not for non-system disks, no.

Comment: @Randolph He only wants to share the non-system disks, since both systems should be on the SSD. At least that's how I understand it. -- so he shouldn't have a problem with this.

Comment: Fair enough. It was more of a "in case of fire" warning. I did vote up your answer after all ;-).